# Opencv source code for all the platforms

Tags: opencv

My question is related to the source codes of Opencv. It seems to me for different platform [the Opencv website](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) provides different code structures. I just wondering whether it is possible to have one source code for all the different platforms. With the same source code, I can compile for different platforms. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OpenCV source code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv).. Just choose the version you need, download and build away to your heart's content. HTH